# How to correct the style of the status bar in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using vim-airline in order to style my status bar, but I can't have it as it should be.
This is how it's looking now:

[image]

This is how it should look:

[image]

You can see that purple areas are not 'sharp-pointed' to the right or the left.
What do you think is happening?

Comment: https://github.com/bling/vim-airline#integrating-with-powerline-fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the nice looking powerline symbols to appear, you will need to install a patched font. Instructions can be found in the official powerline documentation. Prepatched fonts can be found in the powerline-fonts repository.

https://github.com/bling/vim-airline

Comment: Thank you! didn't know about patched fonts in vim.